# Changing the Display area when using a TV as a Monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have hooked up a Toshiba 32" LED monitor (Model # 32DT2U1) It is connected via an HDMI connection. When the tv is used as the computer screen, the display goes off of the screen just enough so that you just barely see the top of the task bar at the bottom of the screen. It is also off the top and both sides by the same amount.

How do I change the display area so that the entire display is on the screen?

Thanks Eric

Comment: Did you try to change resolution or display settings on your Toshiba device?

Answer (score 1):

When my picture was out of frame on my toshiba 42" tv, I used the "native mode" and it fit perfectly in frame on all sides.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Try switching the TV into Game Mode. According to [the manual](http://cdgenp01.csd.toshiba.com/content/support/manuals/userguides/su3311999/32DT_40FT2U1-EN-draft-01-0728.pdf) you can do it by pressing the <kbd>Menu</kbd> button, selecting *Picture* menu and then *Game Mode*.
2. Enable *PC Mode*: press <kbd>Menu</kbd>, select *Picture* and change *Mode* to *PC*.